# Having trouble with implementing a timer in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to create a kivy application.
The Application works as following:

1. I send the amount of seconds I want my timer to last via MQTT over the topic 'tafelxuren' (x is a number between 1 and 8).
2. After sending the amounts of seconds I want it to last, I send a second MQTT command to the topic 'tafelxstart' (x is a number between 1 and 8) with the command 'start'.
3. After sending the start command, my timer starts running.

[image]

Under my timer I have 3 buttons, pause, resume and stop.
While starting and pausing the timer works using MQTT commands, I cannot seem to get my resume button to function properly, if there's 26 seconds left after clicking on the pause button, I want my timer to resume from that point. Instead, it starts again from the beginning

My main.py:

```
import os
if os.name == 'posix':
    os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'gl'
import kivy, time,threading
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.config import Config
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'auto')
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
import paho.mqtt.subscribe as subscribe
import config

# lege MQTT-client instantie
client = None
# De topics die gebruikt worden
ingesteldetijd = [config.timeTopics['tafel1'],config.timeTopics['tafel2'],config.timeTopics['tafel3'],config.timeTopics['tafel4'],config.timeTopics['tafel5'],config.timeTopics['tafel6'],config.timeTopics['tafel7'],config.timeTopics['tafel8']]
ingesteldetijdTopics = [config.tim1, config.tim2, config.tim3, config.tim4, config.tim5, config.tim6, config.tim7, config.tim8]

starttopics = [config.startTopics['tafel1'],config.startTopics['tafel2'],config.startTopics['tafel3'],config.startTopics['tafel4'],config.startTopics['tafel5'],config.startTopics['tafel6'],config.startTopics['tafel7'],config.startTopics['tafel8']]
def on_connect(client,userdata,flags,rc):
        '''
        This function gets triggered when MQTT is connected succesfully
        '''
        if(rc == 0):
            print("[INFO   ] [MQTT        ] MQTT connected to broker "+config.settings['broker']+".")
            client.subscribe('#')
            ##################################### ingestelde tijd subscriptions #####################################
            for x in range(0,8):
                client.subscribe(ingesteldetijd[x])
                print('[INFO   ] [MQTT        ] Subscribed to '+ingesteldetijd[x])
            ##################################### ingestelde tijd subscriptions #####################################

            ##################################### start topic subscriptions #####################################
            for x in range(0,8):
                client.subscribe(starttopics[x])
                print('[INFO   ] [MQTT        ] Subscribed to '+starttopics[x])
            ##################################### start topic subscriptions #####################################
        else:
            print("MQTT connection to broker "+config.settings['broker']+"failed.")


def on_message(client,userdata,msg):
    '''
    If there's a message received on one of the topics, the messages gets handled here.
    '''
    ################################## tijd instellen topic ##################################
    if msg.topic == 'tafel1uren':
        config.tim1 = int(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
    if msg.topic == 'tafel2uren':
        config.tim2 = int(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
    if msg.topic == 'tafel3uren':
        config.tim3 = int(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
    if msg.topic == 'tafel4uren':
        config.tim4 = int(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
    if msg.topic == 'tafel5uren':
        config.tim5 = int(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
    if msg.topic == 'tafel6uren':
        config.tim6 = int(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
    if msg.topic == 'tafel7uren':
        config.tim7 = int(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
    if msg.topic == 'tafel8uren':
        config.tim8 = int(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
    ################################## tijd instellen topic ##################################

    if msg.topic == config.startTopics['tafel1']:
        if msg.payload.decode('utf-8') == 'start':
            config.tb1start = True
        if msg.payload.decode('utf-8') == 'stop':
            config.tb1start = False
    if msg.topic == config.startTopics['tafel2']:
        if msg.payload.decode('utf-8') == 'start':
            config.tb2start = True
        if msg.payload.decode('utf-8') == 'stop':
            config.tb2start = False
    if msg.topic == config.startTopics['tafel3']:
        if msg.payload.decode('utf-8') == 'start':
            config.tb3start = True
        if msg.payload.decode('utf-8') == 'stop':
            config.tb3start = False
    if msg.topic == config.startTopics['tafel4']:
        if msg.payload.decode('utf-8') == 'start':
            config.tb4start = True
        if msg.payload.decode('utf-8') == 'stop':
            config.tb4start = False
    if msg.topic == config.startTopics['tafel5']:
        if msg.payload.decode('utf-8') == 'start':
            config.tb5start = True
        if msg.payload.decode('utf-8') == 'stop':
            config.tb5start = False
    if msg.topic == config.startTopics['tafel6']:
        if msg.payload.decode('utf-8') == 'start':
            config.tb6start = True
        if msg.payload.decode('utf-8') == 'stop':
            config.tb6start = False
    if msg.topic == config.startTopics['tafel7']:
        if msg.payload.decode('utf-8') == 'start':
            config.tb7start = True
        if msg.payload.decode('utf-8') == 'stop':
            config.tb7start = False
    if msg.topic == config.startTopics['tafel8']:
        if msg.payload.decode('utf-8') == 'start':
            config.tb8start = True
        if msg.payload.decode('utf-8') == 'stop':
            config.tb8start = False

class CrudeTimerGrid(GridLayout):
    _python_access = ObjectProperty(None)
    time = NumericProperty(0)
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(CrudeTimerGrid,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.runningTimer = 0
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.load_times,1)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.start,1)

    def load_times(self, *_):
        tafelobjecten = self.parent.parent.ids
        for x in range(0,8):
            if list(tafelobjecten.values())[x] == self:
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel1':
                    self.time = config.tim1
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel2':
                    self.time = config.tim2
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel3':
                    self.time = config.tim3
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel4':
                    self.time = config.tim4
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel5':
                    self.time = config.tim5
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel6':
                    self.time = config.tim6
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel7':
                    self.time = config.tim7
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel8':
                    self.time = config.tim8

    def start(self, *_):
        tafelobjecten = self.parent.parent.ids
        self.runningTimer = self.time
        for x in range(0,8):
            if list(tafelobjecten.values())[x] == self:
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel1':
                    #self.time = config.tim1
                    if config.tb1start == True:
                        if(self.runningTimer > 0):
                            Clock.schedule_interval(self.tick,1)
                elif str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel2':
                    #self.time = config.tim2
                    if config.tb2start == True:
                        if(self.runningTimer > 0):
                            Clock.schedule_interval(self.tick,1)
                elif str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel3':
                    #self.time = config.tim3
                    if config.tb3start == True:
                        if(self.runningTimer > 0):
                            Clock.schedule_interval(self.tick,1)
                elif str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel4':
                    #self.time = config.tim4
                    if config.tb4start == True:
                        if(self.runningTimer > 0):
                            Clock.schedule_interval(self.tick,1)
                elif str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel5':
                    #self.time = config.tim5
                    if config.tb5start == True:
                        if(self.runningTimer > 0):
                            Clock.schedule_interval(self.tick,1)
                elif str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel6':
                    #self.time = config.tim6
                    if config.tb6start == True:
                        if(self.runningTimer > 0):
                            Clock.schedule_interval(self.tick,1)
                elif str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel7':
                    #self.time = config.tim7
                    if config.tb7start == True:
                        if(self.runningTimer > 0):
                            Clock.schedule_interval(self.tick,1)
                elif str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel8':
                    #self.time = config.tim8
                    if config.tb8start == True:
                        if(self.runningTimer > 0):
                            Clock.schedule_interval(self.tick,1)

    def pause(self):
        tafelobjecten = self.parent.parent.ids
        for x in range(0,8):
            if list(tafelobjecten.values())[x] == self:
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel1':
                    config.tb1start = False
                    Clock.unschedule(self.tick)
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel2':
                    config.tb2start = False
                    Clock.unschedule(self.tick)
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel3':
                    config.tb3start = False
                    Clock.unschedule(self.tick)
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel4':
                    config.tb4start = False
                    Clock.unschedule(self.tick)
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel5':
                    config.tb5start = False
                    Clock.unschedule(self.tick)
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel6':
                    config.tb6start = False
                    Clock.unschedule(self.tick)
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel7':
                    config.tb7start = False
                    Clock.unschedule(self.tick)
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel8':
                    config.tb8start = False
                    Clock.unschedule(self.tick)


    def resume(self, *_):
        tafelobjecten = self.parent.parent.ids
        for x in range(0,8):
            if list(tafelobjecten.values())[x] == self:
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel1':
                    config.tb1start = True
                    Clock.schedule_interval(self.tick,1)
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel2':
                    config.tb2start = True
                    Clock.schedule_interval(self.tick,1)
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel3':
                    config.tb3start = True
                    Clock.schedule_interval(self.tick,1)
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel4':
                    config.tb4start = True
                    Clock.schedule_interval(self.tick,1)
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel5':
                    config.tb5start = True
                    Clock.schedule_interval(self.tick,1)
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel6':
                    config.tb6start = True
                    Clock.schedule_interval(self.tick,1)
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel7':
                    config.tb7start = True
                    Clock.schedule_interval(self.tick,1)
                if str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]) == 'tafel8':
                    config.tb8start = True
                    Clock.schedule_interval(self.tick,1)        #pass

    def stop(self, *_):
        #TODO: implement stop button
        pass

    def tick(self, *_):
        tafelobjecten = self.parent.parent.ids
        if self.runningTimer > 0:
            self.runningTimer -= 1
            # publish de juiste tafel topic met de waarde van de restrerende tijd
            for x in range(0,8):
                if list(tafelobjecten.values())[x] == self:
                    client.publish(topic = str(list(tafelobjecten.keys())[x]), payload = str(self.runningTimer))
                    self.ids.Changelabel.text = str(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S',time.gmtime(self.runningTimer)))
        else:
            pass

class Main(GridLayout):
    pass

class CrudeTimerApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.username_pw_set(config.settings['username'], config.settings['password'])
    client.connect(config.settings['broker'])
    t = threading.Thread(target=client.loop_start())
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    CrudeTimerApp().run()
```

My .kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.10.1
################################### Widget template ##########################################
<CrudeTimerGrid>:
    _python_access: Changelabel
    id: timer
    rows: 4
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 0.15
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
            Line:
                width: 2
                rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
        Label:
            font_size: 20
            text: 'Restrerende tijd:'
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
                Line:
                    width: 2
                    rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
        Label:
            font_size: 20
            id: Changelabel
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
                Line:
                    width: 2
                    rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 0.15
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
            Line:
                width: 2
                rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
        Label:
            font_size: 20
            text: 'Pauzetijd:'
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
                Line:
                    width: 2
                    rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
        Label:
            font_size: 20
            text: '00'
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
                Line:
                    width: 2
                    rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 0.2
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
            Line:
                width: 2
                rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
        Button:
            text: "Pauze"
            on_press: timer.pause()
        Button:
            text: "Hervatten"
            on_press: timer.resume()
        Button:
            text: "Stoppen"
            #on_press: timer.reset()
    Label:
        text: ''
################################### Widget template ##########################################

<Main@Widget>:
    rows: 2 # 2 rijen
    cols: 4 # 4 colums
    padding: 10 
    spacing: 10
    ################################### Tafel 1 ##########################################
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
            Line:
                width: 2
                rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            size_hint_y: 0.15
            font_size: 25
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            text: 'Tafel 1'
        CrudeTimerGrid:
            id: tafel1
    ################################### Tafel 1 ##########################################

    ################################### Tafel 2 ##########################################
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
            Line:
                width: 2
                rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            size_hint_y: 0.15
            font_size: 25
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            text: 'Tafel 2'
        CrudeTimerGrid:
            id: tafel2
    ################################### Tafel 2 ##########################################

    ################################### Tafel 3 ##########################################
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
            Line:
                width: 2
                rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            size_hint_y: 0.15
            font_size: 25
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            text: 'Tafel 3'
        CrudeTimerGrid:
            id: tafel3
    ################################### Tafel 3 ##########################################

    ################################### Tafel 4 ##########################################
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
            Line:
                width: 2
                rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            size_hint_y: 0.15
            font_size: 25
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            text: 'Tafel 4'
        CrudeTimerGrid:
            id: tafel4
    ################################### Tafel 4 ##########################################

    ################################### Tafel 5 ##########################################
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
            Line:
                width: 2
                rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            size_hint_y: 0.15
            font_size: 25
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            text: 'Tafel 5'
        CrudeTimerGrid:
            id: tafel5
    ################################### Tafel 5 ##########################################

    ################################### Tafel 6 ##########################################
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
            Line:
                width: 2
                rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            size_hint_y: 0.15
            font_size: 25
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            text: 'Tafel 6'
        CrudeTimerGrid:
            id: tafel6
    ################################### Tafel 6 ##########################################

    ################################### Tafel 7 ##########################################
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
            Line:
                width: 2
                rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            size_hint_y: 0.15
            font_size: 25
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            text: 'Tafel 7'
        CrudeTimerGrid:
            id: tafel7
    ################################### Tafel 7 ##########################################

    ################################### Tafel 8 ##########################################
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
            Line:
                width: 2
                rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            size_hint_y: 0.15
            font_size: 25
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            text: 'Tafel 8'
        CrudeTimerGrid:
            id: tafel8
    ################################### Tafel 8 ##########################################

Main:
```

my config.py:

```
# MQTT broker settings.
settings = dict(
    broker = '172.16.24.128',
    username = 'pi',
    password = 'Piaservice123'
)

# start topics.
startTopics = dict(
    tafel1 = 'tafel1start',
    tafel2 = 'tafel2start',
    tafel3 = 'tafel3start',
    tafel4 = 'tafel4start',
    tafel5 = 'tafel5start',
    tafel6 = 'tafel6start',
    tafel7 = 'tafel7start',
    tafel8 = 'tafel8start'
)

# time in seconds topics.
timeTopics = dict(
    tafel1 = 'tafel1uren',
    tafel2 = 'tafel2uren',
    tafel3 = 'tafel3uren',
    tafel4 = 'tafel4uren',
    tafel5 = 'tafel5uren',
    tafel6 = 'tafel6uren',
    tafel7 = 'tafel7uren',
    tafel8 = 'tafel8uren'
)

# Currenttime topics.
currentTime = dict(
    tafel1 = 'tafel1',
    tafel2 = 'tafel2',
    tafel3 = 'tafel3',
    tafel4 = 'tafel4',
    tafel5 = 'tafel5',
    tafel6 = 'tafel6',
    tafel7 = 'tafel7',
    tafel8 = 'tafel8'
)

# Global timer vars
tim1 = 0
tim2 = 0
tim3 = 0
tim4 = 0
tim5 = 0
tim6 = 0
tim7 = 0
tim8 = 0

# startbooleans
tb1start = False
tb2start = False
tb3start = False
tb4start = False
tb5start = False
tb6start = False
tb7start = False
tb8start = False
```

The class where all the magic happens is the class `CrudeTimerGrid()`.
How can I make it so my timer won't reset everytime I click on my Resume button?

Edit: managed to fix my problem!
I made an event(`self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.tick,1)`) and have 2 buttons to pause and resume.
I use the pause button (`Clock.unschedule(self.event)`) to unschedule the event and the resume button (`Clock.schedule_once(self.event)`) to reschedule my timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to unschedule a Kivy Clock event by using `Clock.unschedule(self.tick)`. Please refer to the example below.

[Kivy Clock » Unscheduling](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#unscheduling)

### Schedule

Replace

```
Clock.schedule_interval(self.tick, 1)
```

with

```
self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.tick, 1)
```

### Unschedule

so that you can unschedule using
either

```
self.event.cancel()
```

or

```
Clock.unschedule(self.event)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and the resetting of time is fixed, but I've still got the problem that when I click my resume button twice, that I get 2 timers running simultaneously which both change the label, you see the time changing between the two timers continously

Comment: Since you have 8 tables/windows, you should have 8 start events i.e. `self.tafel? = Clock.schedule_interval(self.tick, 1)`, and 8 cancel / unschedule events i.e. `Clock.unschedule(self.tafel?)` where ? = 1 to 8.

Comment: Did manage to fix my problem as per your suggestion, the only thing different is a schedule_once to spin up my event again. Thanks for the suggestion, it helped alot!